# Lesser and greater symbols in the axeslabels

Tags: plotting, symbols

I need a plot with $\Gamma^<$ as axeslabel using:

**AxesLabel -> { $\Gamma^<$}**

But I get an error.

**AxesLabel -> { $\Gamma^{a<b}$}** works though.

I think I've to tell mathematica that  $\Gamma^<$ is not a mathematical expression or something in that direction.

Is there some solution for this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe: `AxesLabel -> {Superscript["\[CapitalGamma]", "<"]}`

Comment: @VLC Thank you! That was the solution! Could you make an answer from this comment, then I could rate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show the label correctly you can wrap it between quotation marks. In your case:

`AxesLabel -> {Superscript["\[CapitalGamma]", "<"]}`.

Answer (score 2):

To complement VLC's answer know that you do not need to explicitly enter `Superscript`.  It is sufficient to place the entire label expression into a String.

[image: Mathematica graphics]